# What instructions can be allowed to execute or prohibited from executing in user mode?

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev

There are instructions that the CPU can never be able to execute in user mode (for example: the `HLT` instruction).

And there are instructions that the CPU will always be able to execute in user mode (for example: the `MOV` instruction).

And there are instructions that the CPU can be allowed to execute or prohibited from executing in user mode (for example: the `IN` and `OUT` instructions).

My question is: what are the other instructions (other than `IN` and `OUT`) that can be allowed to execute or prohibited from executing in user mode?

Comment: `MOV` may fail to execute if it violates segment or page protection. And then there are `MOV` instructions that move to/from control registers. At any rate, for an exhaustive list of instructions and conditions (some instructions may be disallowed like `RDTSC`) you should consult the CPU documentation instead of asking here.

Comment: To answer (in part) the last question the IOPL sensitive instructions are `IN`, `INS`, `OUT`, `OUTS`, `CLI`, `STI`

Answer (score 3):

Originally there were three groups:

- instructions that can be executed at any privilege level
- instructions that are sensitive to "IOPL" (IO Privilege Level"). These are `IN` (and variations - byte, word, dword, string), `OUT` (and its variations), `HLT`, `CLI` and `STI`. If IOPL (in eflags) is set to 3 then these instructions can be used in user code (CPL=3); and if IOPL is set to a numerically lower value these instructions can't be used in user code.
- supervisor instructions (e.g. `LGDT`, `WRMSR`, `INVD`, ..., `MOV to/from debug registers`). These can never be executed at CPL=3.

Since then they (CPU manufacturers - Intel, AMD, VIA, ..) have added (in "approximate chronological order"):

- the "alignment check" feature, which disallows misaligned reads and writes at CPL=3
- the RDTSC instruction and a flag (in CR4) to disallow it at CPL=3.
- the "protected mode virtual interrupt" feature that effects the behavior of `CLI` and `STI` at CPL=3 (mostly intended for virtual8086 but not limited to that).
- a flag in an MSR that allows CPL=0 code to disable `CPUID leaves > 2` (make the CPU pretend these leaves don't exist), which is something that was originally a misguided work-around ("software is soft, hardware is hard") for a bug in an old version of WindowsNT, but still hangs around 20+ years later for no sane reason at all.
- all kinds of virtualisation stuff (e.g. `VMENTER`, `VMEXIT`, ...)
- the RDTSCP instruction (access at CPL=3 still controlled by the earlier flag in CR4)
- the `RDPMC` instruction
- the `SWAPGS` instruction
- alternatives to/extensions of `SWAPGS` (`RDFSBASE`, `RDGSBASE`, `WRFSBASE`, etc)
- an extension called "UMIP" (User Mode Instruction Prevention") that (if enabled) mostly prevents user code from using instructions to find out the virtual addresses of kernel data structures (so that "KASR" is slightly less of a joke). The instructions disallowed by this are `SGDT`, `SIDT`, `SLDT`, `SMSW` and `STR`.
- a hidden/undocumented flag in an MSR that allows some kernels (if they're written by developers that are able to find out about it) to disable access to a few more instructions that user code should never have been able to execute (`CPUID` and I don't know what else).

Comment: Note that `IN` and `OUT` are also subject to the permission bitmap in the TSS.

Answer (score 1):

There are several flags in cr4 that control the availability of specific instructions in user mode:

- TSD (bit 2): RDTSC and RDTSCP
- PCE (bit 8): RDPMC
- OSFXSR (bit 9)*: FXSAVE, FXRSTOR, and SSE instructions
- UMIP (bit 11): SGDT, SIDT, SLDT, SMSW, STR
- FSGSBASE (bit 16)*: RDFSBASE, RDGSBASE, WRFSBASE, WRGSBASE

Flags marked with * affect execution of the corresponding instructions in ring 0 also.